# How to access the hashed classname set by CSS Modules in a functional react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class name "nav" and I cannot use querySelector to target it because CSS modules hashes the name of the class to something like nav-xyzxyz. To complicate things a little bit further I need to check if a class exists on an element with the class "nav", but both "is-open" and "nav" are hashed.

```
if (nav.classList.contains("is-open"))
```

Comment: Why not use a `ref` instead of DOM access?

Comment: Don't use the DOM as your app state. Keep that state separate and apply the right classes according to your own data, regardless of the current DOM. Otherwise, you're fighting against React and you'll only face problems.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your info i'm assuming your component code would look something like this:

```
<div class={classes.is-open}></div>
```

but as an alternative you could do something like this:

```
<div className={`${classes.App} is-open`}>
```

However, it sounds like you're trying to achieve something you should be doing with state. I'd look into that first.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use className instead of classList and includes method:

```
if (nav.className.includes("is-open"))
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I target the `document.querySelector(".nav")` when I use CSS modules since the `.nav` class name is hashed.

Comment: From the top of my head - document.querySelector("[class^=nav]")